# How get entitlement for the app, in order to access NEHotspotHelper

Tags: ios9.1, networkextension

How get entitlement for the app, in order to access NEHotspotHelper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to email Apple:

> The com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper entitlement is required in order to use NEHotspotHelper. To request this entitlement, send an email to networkextension@apple.com.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nehotspothelper